# shiny leaflet ploygon click event

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a map called `business` which is downloaded from natural earth website. What I am doing here is I created a basic Map output which shows the map. I am mainly using two columns which are `admin`(which is the name of the country) and `economy` here. Then I added a drop down list called `Business` under ui so that when I click the polygon of the country the list would refresh and show the country that I am clicking. I assume when I write `p <- input$Map_shape_click` shiny would know p is a `business` object so it has column `admin` and I have reference this `admin` ID  to refresh my `Business` drop down list. But it doesn't work.The link shows what I am seeing - the list wouldn't refresh when I click a different country.

[image]

**server.r**

```
country <- readOGR(dsn = tmp, layer = "ne_110m_admin_0_countries", encoding   = "UTF-8")
business<-country[country@data$admin %in% c("Brazil","Colombia","Panama","Kazakhstan","Argentina","India","","Chile","Dominican Republic","United Kingdom","El Salvador","United States of America"),]
business@data$category <- factor(sample.int(20L, nrow(business@data), FALSE))


shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

output$Map <- renderLeaflet({
  factpal <- colorFactor(topo.colors(20), business@data$category)
  state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Name of the country </strong>", 
                        business$admin, 
                        "<br><strong> information is  </strong>", 
                        business$economy)
    leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    addPolygons(data=business,
                layerId=~admin,
                fillColor= ~factpal(category),
                fillOpacity = 0.7, 
                color = "#BDBDC3", 
                weight = 1, 
                popup = state_popup,
                highlight = highlightOptions(
                weight = 5,
                color = "#666",
                dashArray = "",
                fillOpacity = 0.7,
                bringToFront = TRUE))})


observeEvent(input$Map_shape_click, { # update the location selectInput on map clicks
  p <- input$Map_shape_click
  if(!is.null(p$admin)){
    if(is.null(input$Business) || input$Business!=p$admin) updateSelectInput(session, "Business", selected=p$admin)
  }
})
}
)
```

**ui.r**

```
navbarPage("Market Portal",
tabPanel("About",
           bootstrapPage(
             leafletOutput("Map",width="100%",height="800px"),
             absolutePanel(top=100, right=50,
             selectInput("Business", "Business", c("Brazil","Colombia","Panama","Kazakhstan","Argentina","India","Chile","Dominican Republic","United Kingdom","El Salvador","United States of America"), selected="")
))))
```

Comment: the return values from the `map_shape_click` are the coordinates (`lat`, `lng`), and the `id` (which is the `layerId` value), so I think you want `p$id` in stead of `p$admin`

Comment: You are my hero!! Perfectly soled the problem!!

Comment: You're welcome; I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 25):

The `click` event in leaflet returns `lat`, `lng` and `id` (and a random value). So you can only access one of those elements.

The `id` value relates to the `layerId` you specify in the shape plotting function, so in your case that's `layerId=~admin`.

So you acccess the `admin` value through the click's `id` field

replace `p$admin` with `p$id` and you should have your solution.

---

If you want to see what's in the `click` event, just put a `print` statement around it

```
observeEvent(input$Map_shape_click, { # update the location selectInput on map clicks
  p <- input$Map_shape_click
  print(p)
})
```

and it will print the object to the console.

Comment: i keep getting null values

Comment: @JohnAlexander ookkaaayyy...? You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @JohnAlexander I am sure the problem is long gone, but it could be that you need to adjust the name of the variable. For instance, my map object is called "mymap", not "Map". So I need to use input$mymap_shape_click, rather than input$Map_shape_click.