# Click polygon and will updateselectinput() - (using leaflet R)

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

Currently i've managed to align the data with the shape file and plot each region to the map. The polygon is added layer to segregate each region giving more information to whats going on in that region.
what i'm trying to do is that, user should be able to click on the polygon and this should update the inputselect option.

i tried to use Observe() with updateselectinput() but i dont think its working

```css
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(rgdal)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sgmap55 <-readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aeiyuni/regioncount/master/55_MP14_PLNG_AREA_WEB_PL.kml")
wfmap <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aeiyuni/regioncount/master/wfmap.csv")

## to check if all the data matches




bins <-c(1,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500)
pal <- colorBin("YlGnBu", domain = wfmap$count, bins = bins, na.color = "#808080")

labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g respondents </sup>",
  wfmap$planarea, wfmap$count
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)


##_----------------------------


ui<- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("region", "Planning Area:", 
                choices = wfmap$planarea)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    leafletOutput("sgmap2", height= "1000px"))
   
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$sgmap2 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addSearchOSM()%>%
      addResetMapButton()%>%
      clearMarkers()%>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
      setView(103.8198,1.3521,12) %>%
      addPolygons(data = sgmap55,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  smoothFactor = 0.5,
                  fillOpacity = 0.8,
                  fillColor = pal(wfmap$count),
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666666",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE),
                  label = labels,
                  labelOptions = labelOptions(
                    style = list("font-weight" = "normal",
                                 padding = "3px 8px"),
                    textsize = "15px",
                    direction = "auto"),
                  group = "By region")%>%
      addLegend(pal = pal,
                values = wfmap$count,
                opacity = 0.7,
                position = "topright")
    
  })

  
###<<<< observe() code here      
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When i added Observe(), it stop working.

```css
  ##trial code starts here----
  observe({
    
    event <- input$insgmap2_shape_click
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "region", selected = event$Name
    )
    
  })
  ## trial code end here------
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798377/shiny-leaflet-ploygon-click-event/42798668#42798668) may be relevant

Comment: i saw this, and tried. It doesnt work since i have multiple layers on the map.

Comment: You get the layer through the `layerId` value

Comment: no.. i use 2x addpolygon()

Comment: this is what i'm trying to achieve:
https://compassnz.shinyapps.io/NZIPR/

where the map correspond to the selectinput.

Comment: i've edited, this time it is reproducible.. i remove all the layers and keep the one that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. As per my comment, you need to specify the `layerId` as the `~Name`. This will then be returned in the `id` field of the click event.

You also had an error in your `observe()` event. You weren't referencing the correct map name. I've fixed this for you (see my comment in the `observe()` function)

I've also included a `print(event)` statement so you can see the data that gets returned when you click on the layer

```r
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(rgdal)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sgmap55 <- readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aeiyuni/regioncount/master/55_MP14_PLNG_AREA_WEB_PL.kml")
wfmap <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aeiyuni/regioncount/master/wfmap.csv")


bins <-c(1,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500)
pal <- colorBin("YlGnBu", domain = wfmap$count, bins = bins, na.color = "#808080")

labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g respondents </sup>",
  wfmap$planarea, wfmap$count
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)


ui<- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("region", "Planning Area:", 
                choices = wfmap$planarea)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    leafletOutput("sgmap2", height= "1000px"))

)


server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$sgmap2 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addSearchOSM()%>%
      addResetMapButton()%>%
      clearMarkers()%>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
      setView(103.8198,1.3521,12) %>%
      addPolygons(data = sgmap55,
                  weight = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  smoothFactor = 0.5,
                  fillOpacity = 0.8,
                  fillColor = pal(wfmap$count),
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666666",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE),
                  label = labels,
                  labelOptions = labelOptions(
                    style = list("font-weight" = "normal",
                                 padding = "3px 8px"),
                    textsize = "15px",
                    direction = "auto"),
                  group = "By region",
                  layerId = ~Name
                  ) %>%
      addLegend(pal = pal,
                values = wfmap$count,
                opacity = 0.7,
                position = "topright")

  })

  observe({

    ## the sgmap2 needs to match the name of the map you're outputting above
    event <- input$sgmap2_shape_click
    print( event )
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "region", selected = event$id
    )

  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```